# Batch clipping Shapefiles using Argparse

Tags: arcpy, command-line

Is there a way to batch clip shapefiles in ArcPy using an argument-Argparse (which calls a shapefile or group of shapefiles) specified by an outside user in command line?

Comment: Why not use model builder to do this?

Comment: You mention argparse in your title but not in your question body. What is its relevance to your question?  Do you perhaps have a code snippet that you can post to show where you are stuck.

Comment: Model Builder will not work because I'm trying to create a script that runs outside of the ArcGIS environment.

Comment: We also wish to use something like Argparse. By listing the variables in the command prompt and passing them to the ArcPy script we can take advantage of enterprise workflow tools like the Decisions application. The benefit of this is we have a single ArcPy script paired with many workflows maintained in a better system.

Answer (score 1):

In the command prompt: call python exe, then the arcpy script, then list the variables in order. The variables can be picked up with argparse in the exact same order. This example works for a known number of variables, on ArcGIS 10.3.1.

```
import arcpy
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("vars",nargs='+')   # naming it "vars"
args = parser.parse_args()         # returns data from the options specified (vars)
Shapefile1 = (args.vars[0])
Shapefile2 = (args.vars[1])
```

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html